# Mysql CURDATE() -1

Tags: mysql, date

Please, I don't understand why this command returns *00 April*.

Today is *1st April 2015*, and executing:

```
mysql> SELECT CURDATE() -1;
```

it returns:

```
| 20150400 |

+--------------+
```

Why `CURDATE-1` doesn't return *31st March*?,

*00 April* is an error, please it would be great if somebody could explain it.

Next, on *2nd April* it works well, also for the rest of the days within the month:

mysql>

```
select CURDATE() -1;

|     20150401 |
```

This function seems is not able to operate with *+x / -x* out of the current month scope.

This should be highlighted in the reference guide.

BTW, I'vereplaced it with this new function:

```
 SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

You need to use `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

What are you doing with `CURDATE() - 1`, is treating the result of `CURDATE()` as an integer, not a date.

So on April 1st, `CURDATE() - 1` = `20150401 - 1` = `20150400`, which is clearly an invalid date.

MySQL can't intuit this for you, because with `-1` it doesn't know if you mean one less day, one less month, one less year, etc.

Using MySQL's date intervals as above is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pala_ for your clarifications, indeed now I'm using >  SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)    , I think is Ok as well.

Answer (score 13):

You can use:

```
SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1);
```

or

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

or

```
SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```